# Laravel how to get distinct data from database?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have tried as following code,

```
$impressions = DB::table('journey_content_impression')->distinct('journey_item_id')
                ->where('user_id', 91)
                ->where('journey_id',548)->get();
dd($impressions->count());//4 items
```

DB columns as below:

**journey_item_id**

1. 2323
2. 2323
3. 2323
4. 2323

it has 4 same data in the column.

As a result of this, it gives 4 data. Why it gives 4 items, how to get as 1 item?

Comment: `$impressions` is a laravel collection, so you can use the collection method `unique()` to get the distinct values only.

Answer (score 0):

you should select the columns you want to let [distinct](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_distinct)() method make sense ...

by the way .. distinct method take no parameters ... it is only remove duplicated results ....

```
  $impressions = DB::table('journey_content_impression')
            ->where('user_id',
->where('journey_id',548)->select('journey_item_id')->distinct()->get();
```

Comment: but I want to get all columns, how can i do for it?